# Codeception how to grab entities by values in array

Tags: php, symfony4, codeception

I need to grab many entities by values in array.

Method bellow:

```
$arrayOfIds = [1,2,3,4,5];
$I->grabEntitiesFromRepository(Product::class, ['id' => $arrayOfIds]);
```

Return:

> [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\SyntaxErrorException] An exception occurred
>   while executing 'SELECT p0_.id
>   AS id_2, p0_.created_at AS created_at_3, p0_.updated_at AS
>   updated_at_4 FROM product p0_ WHERE p0_.id = ?, ?, ?, ?, ?' with
>   params [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
>
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ', 2, 3, 4, 5'
>   at line 1

Comment: You are passing array as an id/integer, which is showing error. Easy methods: Use findById in a loop or findAll and select the once you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a way to do it:

```
$arrayOfIds = [1,2,3,4,5];
$products = array();
foreach($arrayOfIds as $id){
   $products = array_merge($products, $I->grabEntitiesFromRepository(Product::class, ['id' => $id]));
}
```

$products keeps on adding new products by all IDs.