# How to query row with any value from a parameter array matching any value from a doctrine array

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, dql

I've got an entity with a Doctrine column DC2TYPE fake array.
I would like to create a query fetching any result from this table that got a match between any value of the parameter array, and the doctrine array.
The parameter array is just a classic numeric array.

I've tried things like this.

```
$queryBuilder->select('p.country')
             ->where('p.classification IN (:class)')
             ->setParameter('class',$class);
```

**or with Member of syntax, or with like, or with putting %.**

So far on stack overflow all the tips i've found were working with attributes of entities that were part of a join column, or there was need for one matching from parameter or one matching from the column.

May be this isn't possible?

The function in repo looks like something like this.

```
    public function getCountCountryByClass(array $class,int $clientId){
        $class4='G01N';
        $queryBuilder= $this->createQueryBuilder('p');
        $queryBuilder->select('p.country')
                     ->where('p.classification IN (:class)')
                     ->setParameter('class',$class);
    }
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Depends on method, most of time there is no result

Comment: do you get empty result or null ?

Comment: i get an empty array,never null, sometime i get a dql error with IN but it has'nt been the case this morning (or i get one with member of but it seems it's not the  correct usage so it's pretty normal)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53828401/codeception-how-to-grab-entities-by-values-in-array/53970370#53970370

This might be useful to you.

Comment: Thanks. I did it this way, it's a pretty clean way to do it with a foreach, but i thought there could be a way to do it directly in DQL